# Unit Test Spring Boot MessageSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am using MessageSource in managing my error messages for my application.

My error messages are inside the file **error_messages.properties** in **src/main/resources/messages**.

Below is my configuration for my MessageSource

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan("mypackage")
@EnableJpaRepositories("mypackage")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "mypackage"})
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("messages/error_messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

Below is my component in loading and using the MessageSource (based on [this](https://gist.github.com/jonikarppinen/0d600b0c82edce890310))

```
@Component
public class ErrorMessages {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        return accessor.getMessage(code);
    }

}
```

Now this is my Service layer.

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{

    @Autowired
    private ErrorMessages errorMessages;

    @Override
    public String getExampleMessage(){
        return String.format(errorMessages.get("default.error"), "default");
    }

}
```

my properties file

```
default.error=Default error with some default message %s.
```

This works fine when I run the application. Now my problem is when I run this in my unit test, I want it to actually fetch the error message from the property file. Since it's a MockBean I have to stub a return value for it and I don't want to do that.

How do I do it?

Below is my test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyServiceImplTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class MyServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public MyService myService() {
            return new MyServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    // I want to avoid mocking this.
    @MockBean
    private ErrorMessages errorMessages;

    @Test
    public void testGetExampleMessage() {
        String expected = "Default error with some default message default.";
        assertEquals(expected, myService.getExampleMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: you can actually start spring, and load these two beans using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`. see this example https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-spring-integration-example/

Comment: also check for more recent Spring Boot versions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166601/springboot-mockito-test-and-autowired-messagesource-in-controller-org-springfram

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your test class:

```java
@ImportAutoConfiguration(MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```